# Android app location with speed

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I'm making an Android app and need to use GPS for recording a drivers statistics such as Speed, heading, altitude and long/lat with a good accuracy.

I need to track the location every second but i don't seem to be getting accurate results.  I've tried an Android GPS app on the market and that returns correct results.

So far I have this.

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider =  locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    VehicleListener vl = new VehicleListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, vl);

    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        lat =location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how the results are not accurate? Also, are you testing it outside to have full GPS visibility?

Comment: I am testing indoors upstairs but it seems to give me a reading of a road away from my current location using Network provider.  Using GPS, it gives me a reading a little bit further than the Network Provider.  Strange thing is I am running an app called GPS Tracker i found that gives the precise location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a empty Criteria. If you desire more accuracy try with this:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
provider =  locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
VehicleListener vl = new VehicleListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, vl);

if (location != null) {
    System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
    lat =location.getLatitude();
    lon = location.getLongitude();
}
```